# Unknown Character then Segfault while Getting String Slices

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am having a very odd issue. I believe it has to do with string slicing but it's difficult for me to even find my error.

My code is as follows:

```
char * readSlice (char * buf, int pos, int len) {
    char * str = malloc(len);
    memcpy(str, buf + pos, len);
    return str;
}

void writeSlice (char * str, char * buf, int pos, int len) {
    memcpy(buf + pos, str, len);
    free(str);
}

char * intToStr (int i, int l) {
    char * s = malloc(l);
    for (int j = 0; j < l; j++) {
        *(s + j) = (i / pow(10, l - j - 1)) + '0';
        i = i % (int) pow(10, l - j - 1);
    }
    return s;
}

int strToInt (char * s, int l) {
    printf("%s\n", s);
    int i = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < l; j++) {
        i += (*(s + j) - '0') * pow(10, l - j - 1);
    }
    free(s);
    return i;
}

void ReadString (char * s) {
    struct MyS * n = malloc (sizeof n);
    n->first = strToInt(readSlice(s, 0, 4), 4);
    for (int i = 1; i < 16; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", i);
        (n->other)[i] = strToInt(readSlice(s, i * 4, 4), 4);
    }
}

int main () {
    ReadString("0000000100020003000400050006000700080009001000110012001300140015");
}
```

This code should print out

```
0000
1
0001
2

...

15
0015
```

However, it  print out

```
0000
1
0001[?]
2
0002[?]

...

6
0006[?]
Segmentation Fault
```

Where [?] is a single character.

However, when I remove all the calls to free() it works just fine (minus the leaks).

I have no idea what I am doing wrong...

Comment: `struct MyS* n = malloc(sizeof n);` should be `struct MyS* n = malloc(sizeof *n);` - You are allocating space for _a pointer_, not a `struct MyS`. Enable more warnings to catch these things

Comment: That... actually fixes the segfault problem. With this change the code runs. However It still outputs the mystery character.

Comment: Cool. if you update the question with a [mre] so that we can also compile it, someone will probably point out the error within minutes.

Comment: The `readSlice` doesn't create a null-terminated string, so the pointer it returns can't be used with any functions that expect it. Like for example the `printf("%s\n", s)` call you have. That will lead to 
*undefined behavior*.

Comment: You are missing headers, and the declaration of `struct MyS`.  Easy fix for `readSlice()` not returning a `\0`  terminated string is to use `strndup()`.

Comment: `strToInt(char *s; ...) { ...; free(s); }` is an anti-pattern.  As a user of the function, I would be very surprised to find it modifying `s` destructively.   It's much cleaner for the creator of `s` to own it.  (eg, `s = malloc(...); ...; strToInt(s, ...); free(s);`)

Answer (score 2):

1. The pattern for allocating space with `malloc()` using sizeof of a variable is:

   ```
   sturct MyS *n = malloc(sizeof *n);
   ```

   You only allocated space for a pointer with `sizeof n` which is 8 bytes and `sizeof(struct MyS)` is (at least) 34 bytes (on my system).  Subsequent use of `n` result a buffer overflow which is undefined behavior.
2. `readSlice()` doesn't return a `\0` terminated string.  This makes the `printf()` in `strToInt()` undefined behavior.  I would just use `strndup()` in `readSlice()` (then refactor and eliminate `readSlice()` as it does nothing):

   ```
   char *readSlice (char *buf, int pos, int len) {
       return strndup(buf + pos, len);
   }
   ```
3. Include missing headers.
4. Declare `struct MyS`.
5. Use symbolic constants instead of magic values (`16`).
6. (Not fixed) Consider using integer math instead of `pow()`.
7. Prefer `s[j]` to `*(s + j)`.  It's shorter and easier to read.
8. (Not fixed) Consider using `strtol()`.  You need a bit of wrapper code to check that it was successful and within the expected range if you don't want a `long` result.

Here is the resulting code:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

enum {
    OTHER_LEN = 16
};

struct MyS {
    int first;
    int other[OTHER_LEN];
};

char *readSlice (char *buf, int pos, int len) {
    return strndup(buf + pos, len);
}

void writeSlice (char *str, char *buf, int pos, int len) {
    memcpy(buf + pos, str, len);
    free(str);
}

char *intToStr (int i, int l) {
    char *s = malloc(l);
    for (int j = 0; j < l; j++) {
        s[j] = (i / pow(10, l - j - 1)) + '0';
        i = i % (int) pow(10, l - j - 1);
    }
    return s;
}

int strToInt (char *s, int l) {
    printf("%s\n", s);
    int i = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < l; j++) {
        i += (s[j] - '0') * pow(10, l - j - 1);
    }
    free(s);
    return i;
}

void ReadString (char *s) {
    struct MyS *n = malloc(sizeof *n);
    n->first = strToInt(readSlice(s, 0, 4), 4);
    for (int i = 1; i < OTHER_LEN; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", i);
        (n->other)[i] = strToInt(readSlice(s, i * 4, 4), 4);
    }
}

int main(void) {    
    ReadString("0000000100020003000400050006000700080009001000110012001300140015");
}
```

and output:

```
0000
1
0001
2
0002
3
0003
4
0004
5
0005
6
0006
7
0007
8
0008
9
0009
10
0010
11
0011
12
0012
13
0013
14
0014
15
0015
```